# Regular expression find exact match in string

Tags: regex

I am new to regex. I'm trying to get lines that exactly only have 0.0 in it.

I want to grab this string

```
3/6/7   56   0.0  0   0   5   0.00
```

But not this

```
3/6/7   56   1.0  0   0   5   0.00
```

I have tried the `^.*0\.0` regex, but, unfortunately, both strings match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\b` word boundary that is available in most regex flavors:

`^.*\b0\.0\b.*$`

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/yA0kF7/2)

Note that if you are using it in Notepad++, the regex above is sufficient, but in some other applications, you might need to specify the `Multiline` option for it to work. You can then use an inline operator `(?m)`: `(?m)^.*\b0\.0\b.*$`

Another note: if you mean to only match a string where `0.0` is separated from the rest with just spaces (or string boundaries), you an use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/yA0kF7/3): `(?:^.* |^)0\.0(?: .*$|$)` or `(^.* |^)0\.0( .*$|$)` if your engine does not support non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dot as is means "any character" in a RegEx. In order to match only lines with one occurrence you can use a negative look ahead.

```
^.*0\.0(?!0\.0)
```

Looksaheads and behinds are not working in all RegEx environments, so it might be that's not an option. A good source is this page http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I wrote that in my question but it did not post that way. I tried but it still gets both strings.

Comment: Thank you I tried this and do not have the option of using a ?.  I'll read up on the link you provided to see if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) meta-character around `0.0` to specify that the term should not be bounded by other digits or letters.

```
/\b0\.0\b/
```

EDIT:

If your language or regexp flavor does not support `\b`, here is another option:

```
/(^| )0\.0( |$)/
```

This basically requires that `0.0` be bounded by a space or the beginning of the string on the left side, and a space or the end of the string on the right side.

Comment: What language are you using? Perhaps `\b` is not supported (or supported correctly) in the language you are using. Here is a [working example](http://refiddle.com/refiddles/55109f9e75622d7800512100).

Comment: I am on Cisco router.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't surprise me to learn that `\b` is not supported on a Cisco router. You might try `/(^0\.0 | 0\.0 | 0\.0$)/`. That basically says `0.0` must be bounded by a space on one side, then the beginning of the string, the end of the string, or another space on the other side. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your line always look like

```
3/6/7   56   0.0  0   0   5   0.00
```

And you can assume that the last number, the leading date the the number after are always there and that last number should not be matched the most simplistic solution to match the entire line would be

```
/^.* 0\.0 .*$/
```